# Erratic 403 errors from Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I was getting very erratic 403 errors from nginx when opening the pages using firefox (mac).

I thought that i made the error go away by disabling the do-not-track feature in Firefox, but it reappeared.
Sometimes a page works, then the next (or after a refresh) i get the 403 again.

It would be very helpfull if someone could point out why this is happening, and how to fix it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found something: it seems my compuyter was switching randomly between ipv4 and ipv6. With an ipv6 address it would not be allowed on this test site, and get a 403.
How curious.
Disabling ipv6 entirely seems to have resolved it.